# How can I change the color of startIconDrawable attribute of TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I'm trying to change the color of `startIconDrawable` attribute of `TextInputLayout` when the state is focused but i can't find a way to do this!

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/Login_Fragment_Email_Text_Input"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:background="@drawable/text_input_top_selector"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Login_Fragment_Logo_Image"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/profile"
    app:startIconTint="@drawable/icon_color_edit_text_selector">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/Login_Fragment_Email_Edit_Text"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-8dp"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:theme="@style/CustomEditText" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I tried to do this by creating `icon_color_edit_text_selector.xml` which contain the following

```java
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorAccent" android:state_focused="true"  />
    <item android:color="@color/iconColor" android:state_focused="false"/>
</selector>
```

but it only shows the default color which is `state_focused ="false"`

Answer (score 3):

You could use startIconTint attribute:

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout.html#attr_TextInputLayout_startIconTint

or if you want to do it in code, you could use setStartIconTintList:

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout.html#setStartIconTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList)

**UPDATE**
To change the color only when the edit text has focus, you should add an on focus listener to the view, but then, this arises a problem since the text input layout does not take focus. But, instead the TextInputEditText takes focus. So you should add an on focus listener to the instance of text input edittext instead. Here is a sample:

```java
// You could simplify this with lambda's
// The variable names i used here matches the id's you have shown on your xml
edit1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        textInputLayout.setStartIconTintList(hasFocus ? ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED) : ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.BLUE));
    }
});
```

Comment: I want to change the color when the state is focused only, so how can i do this behavior?

Comment: i updated my answer to show you how to use setStartIconTintList when the state is focused

Comment: is this the optimal solution? I mean i need to do this for every `EditText`!

Comment: No, you could still make a subclass of textinputlayout that requires a textinputedittext. If you need a more optimal way to do this, tell me so i could help you further.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean by `you could still make a subclass of textinputlayout that requires a textinputedittext`, Can you please update the answer and show me an alternative way that don't require to write many repeated code?

Comment: Is there is a way to do this through `style` or `drawable` file?

Comment: Let me get back to you on 5:00 UTC+8. I'm currently at work.

Comment: I updated the question with what i've tried, hope you can help me.

Comment: hey, i'm really sorry for not updating this. Could you tell me on wther you are using kotlin or java? so i could show this to you through code

Comment: i'm using java, but i'm trying to do this through xml, if it's possible, if it's not possible then can you show me how to do it through code.